# Razor view for a many to many relationship

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework, razor

I have a very basic question with the Razor views.

I want to make a View for this model for creation and deletion.

Model is as follows

```
public class RolePriviledgeModel
{
    [Key]
    public int RolePriviledgeId { get; set; }
    public RoleModel Role { get; set; }
    public PriviledgeModel Priviledge { get; set; }
    public ICollection<PriviledgeModel> Priviledges { get; set; }

}
```

I want to have two drop down list boxes for selecting the User ID and Role ID on the view.

How to get the role ids and priviledge ids from the DB Context and where to use the function?

Comment: Where are User ID and Role Id you are referring to defined?

Comment: It is referring from the User Model and Role Model. I need to create a user to role mapping here.

Comment: Do you want user IDs displayed in one dropdown list and Role IDs in another dropdown list? Do you also want to post the selection to your controller?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a ViewModel which will have Users and priviledges as its properties. In your controller, fetch data from database , populate the View-model and finally send it to view.
Your view can display the drop down list boxes using '@Html.DropDownListFor()' method.
for example:

### Your view model

```
   public class UserRoleViewModel
   {
    int userId {get;set;}
    SelectList Users{get;set;};
    int RoldeId {get;set;}
    SelectList Roles{get;set;}    
   }
```

### In Your Controller:

```
UserRoleViewModel urvm=new UserRoleViewModel();
urvm.users= new SelectList(db.Users.ToList(), "UserId","UserName");
urvm.Roles= new SelectList(db.Roles.ToList(),"RoleId","RoleName");
return View(urvm);
```

### In your View

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.UserId, Model.Users);
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.RoleId, Model.Roles);
```

Hope this helps. Good luck

Comment: Hi Bishnu, It worked. Provided there is some modification needed